# DataGridView CheckBox, revert the Value after user confirmation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a program and it looks like this

[image]

please be focused on the value the one with checked and color red.

Lets say I will click a cell (checkboxcolumn)

if I click a cell a Msgbox will show first sayon `Are you you want to update changes?`

If I click `Yes` the program will check its current value and Update it something like this.

```vb
If value = yes then
   value = No
ElseIf value = no then
   value = Yes
end if
```

and if I select `NO` in the msgbox the value of the current cell will remains the same.

here is my code

```vb
If (e.ColumnIndex = 1 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
    Dim value = DirectCast(DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue, Nullable(Of Boolean))
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to uncheck item?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    If (value.HasValue AndAlso value = True) Then
        If (result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
            If DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True Then
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = False
            Else
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
            End If
        ElseIf (result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No) Then
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If
```

My Question is.

How can I check the the value of cell and turn it vice-versa when I click Yes in the messagebox? and Remains the value or return to its original value when I click NO in the messagebox.

I try my code above but it looks not working

TYSM

Comment: You are asking them if they are sure they want to UNCHECK before you have checked if it IS checked.  You must hate your users.

Comment: Seriously Sir I hate them for real, Please help me sir

Comment: Help with *what*?  You did not ask a question and the text of the post does not match the code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot I will edit my post

Comment: @Plutonix please see the edited post sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such criteria:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
        Dim value = DirectCast(DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue, _
                               Nullable(Of Boolean))
        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to change vaule?", "", _
                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
        If (result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
            If (value.HasValue AndAlso value = True) Then
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = False
            Else
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In above code I showed a confirm message to the user and the if the user choose `Yes`, I reverted the value of cell.

In the above code I used `e.ColumnIndex = 0` to show the confirm for first column. You may need some other criteria, for example `e.ColumnIndex = 1`. Or as another example `(e.ColumnIndex >=1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex <=13)`.

`e.RowIndex >= 0` Makes sure the event is handled for a data cell and not a header cell.